# How to properly set height and width in percent?

Tags: html, css

I need to show a picture and text next to it, but the problem is that the picture is too big and I need to reduce it by setting custom `width` and `height`.

**CSS:**

```
#list{
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    padding:5px;
    /*display: none;*/
}

.info{
    border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding:0 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info .image{
    width:20%;
    height:30%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px
}

.info .image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.info .text_data{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="list" class="select_block">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/screens/screenshot.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="text_data">
            <p>
                Name: Some name
                <br />
                Start: 2012-05-17 04:43:40
                <br />
                End: 2012-05-17 04:43:40
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/e5hyX/

In Firefox it's like 
[image: firefox]

In Safari (probably in chrome is the same)
[image: safari]

So I need something like this (hover on the picture shows it in full size, so I only need a list of previews, **but with percentage**).

[image: need]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only set the height or the width, the browser will scale the image in proportion to its natural dimensions. If you need to make sure that it stays inside a given area, make sure you use the `max-*` properties. For example:

```
width:50%;
max-width:100px;
max-height:80px;
```

Comment: @Kirix just to be clear, you tried removing either the `height` or the `width` from both `.info .image` and `.info .image img`. Correct? `height` can be wacky sometimes, try getting rid of it and only working with widths.

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/updated.png as you can see on the screen - there is a space in red square, but the green is in full height - how to do this for both?